# Ajax Control Toolkit in SP2013

Tags: 2013, master-page, ajax-control-tookit, register

Has anyone ever used the Ajax Control Toolkit in SP2013?
It seems that I don't get it working.

I've added the AjaxControlToolkit.dll to my package (with safecontrols)
And in my masterpage I reference to it by:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit"  Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.7.1005, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" %>
```

But I still get the error message:

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
```

After deployment I do an "IISRESET" and the AjaxControlToolkit.dll can be found in the GAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you dont need it in bin directory! the issue is the version! you need the latest version of ajaxcontroltoolkit! having what you done so far is correct! having it within a project should add it to the gac(assembly) as it should be strongly named!

like i said its todo with the version! have you tried version 3.5?

http://sharepointajax.codeplex.com/releases/view/93640

also look at:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/60fa19fe-86a0-446b-b61f-11a82fe4287f/how-to-implement-ajax-toolkit-for-sharepoint2013?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: Is it possible that changing my ScriptManager to the ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager to fail my claims based authentication? I always get an error that my user cannot be found... (only with changing the scriptmanager)

Comment: Ok, ignore the last comment... Eventually got it working. Following your second link! It was indeed the version that threw the problem. Many thanks!

Comment: no probs happy to help! i had a strong feeling that it was todo with the version type as it was the same for 2007 and 2010 :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to Add you AjaxControlToolkit.dll to Sharepoint site IIS directory -> Bin folder.

"c:\inetpub\WWWroot\Wss\VirtulDirectory(Port Number Folder)\Bin\"

Thats it.

Comment: Also did this. But it still doesn't work

Comment: you can download Ajaxtoolkit from [ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/109918)

Comment: 1. Add AjaxControlToolkit.dll reference to your project.
2. Add Ajax Control Toolkit ScriptManager in master page.
3. Register Ajax Control Toolkit namespaces in SharePoint package Designer.